# User online indicator in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, custom-view

I need to achieve the indicator below which shows that the user is online, and has empty borders between image and actual indicator.

How can I achieve it?

Maybe canva is the key, but I do not know how. Please help me produce the indicator.

[image]

Comment: You could use a canvas. draw a circle with orange and text in center and then use radius of the circle to calculate a point on the circumference of the bigger circle. Use that as the center to draw the smaller circle

Comment: @Raghunandan The thing is I use avatar as an image, not as an Canvas element.

Comment: you could draw a image on canvas. You could use a Box i guess in this case as well

Comment: @Raghunandan, Yes i could use Box, but how i can achieve the empty distance between image and indicator?

Comment: There is an example in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#compositing-strategy) that might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Canvas instead of workaround of adding white border to image, you can checkout below code:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Rect
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp


Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            val imageWidth = 50.dp.toPx()
            val radius = imageWidth / 2f
            val overlapAmount = radius / 3f
            val iconSize = overlapAmount * 2f
            val iconCenterX = (size.width / 2f) + (imageWidth / 2f) - overlapAmount
            val iconCenterY = (size.height / 2f) + (imageWidth / 2f) - overlapAmount
            val arcStartAngle = 135f // Start angle for the arc in degrees
            val arcSweepAngle = 180f // Sweep angle for the arc in degrees
            val arcRect = Rect(
                left = (iconCenterX - iconSize / 2f),
                top = (iconCenterY - iconSize / 2f),
                right = (iconCenterX + iconSize / 2f),
                bottom = (iconCenterY + iconSize / 2f)
            )
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Gray,
                radius = radius,
                center = Offset(size.width / 2f, size.height / 2f)
            )
            drawArc(
                color = Color.White,
                startAngle = arcStartAngle,
                sweepAngle = arcSweepAngle,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = arcRect.topLeft,
                size = Size(arcRect.width, arcRect.height),
                style = Stroke(width = 10f)
            )
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Green,
                radius = iconSize / 2f,
                center = Offset(iconCenterX, iconCenterY)
            )
        }
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.alerter_ic_notifications), // Replace with your profile image resource
            contentDescription = "Profile Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(20.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
```

Here is sample output:

[Profile image using canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJOJg.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do with border property of modifier to the blue dot and add some dp of border to look like that hope you find this helpful.

**Edit:-** You can use badge compoable function to make UI something like this here is [link](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/badgedbox/)

**Example:-**

```
@Composable
fun DrawUser(users: List<User>) {
    LazyRow(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        items(users) {
            Box {
                Image(
                    bitmap = it.image.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = "user",
                    modifier = Modifier.clip(
                        CircleShape
                    )
                )
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.dot),
                    contentDescription = "dot",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(
                            CircleShape
                        )
                        .border(5.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = CircleShape)
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

data class User(val image: Bitmap)
```

I have my blog [here](https://medium.com/@heetkanabar/custom-user-online-indicator-in-jetpack-compose-4e2fe4ed6635)